# Feeling difficulty in extjs combo

Tags: extjs

I have a multiselect combo. When a user select a value from combo then the value get displayed. Now I want add a string in the value choosed by the user and it should be displayed in combo not the selected value of the user

Comment: What version of ExtJS?

Comment: I am using extjs 5

Comment: so you have two combos?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for the displayTpl config of your combobox (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-displayTpl)

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    multiSelect: true,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        render: function(combo) {
            combo.setDisplayTpl(
                '{[values instanceof Array ? values.length === 1 ? values[0]["' + combo.displayField + '"] : values.length + " values selected" : values]}'
            )
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bqu